# C++ template parameters in method definitions

Tags: c++, templates

Do all method declarations in a class that has a template parameter need to be declared with that parameter?  The compiler seems to want something like the following

```
// Queue.h
template <class ItemType>
class Queue
{
    Queue();
    ItemType dequeue();
    int count();
    /* ... other methods ... */
};
// Queue.cpp
template <class ItemType>
Queue<ItemType>::Queue()
{ /*...*/ }
template <class ItemType>
int Queue<ItemType>::count()
{/*...*/}
template <class ItemType>
ItemType Queue<ItemType>::dequeue()
{/* ... */}
```

Coming from Java/C#, this seems a bit redundant--I feel like I should be able to define the methods more like this:

```
int Queue::count()
```

The signature does not reference ItemType, so we can omit it.

```
Queue::ItemType Queue::dequeue()
```

The signature references ItemType, but the compiler knows that we're talking about the template parameter because we qualify the identifier with `Queue::`

Comment: Technically speaking you are not asking about *declarations*, but about the *definitions* of members declared in the class template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to provide the template argument. Note that while it might look redundant, it is not. C++ templates are a much more powerful tool that Java generics, and they allow for specializations. That means that with a base template `Queue` there might be multiple implementations that match different template arguments and have different definitions. Alternatively, you can have a single `Queue` template with multiple specializations for some functions. These two situations require you to provide both the `template` argument list an the class template arguments:

```
// Just member specialization
template <typename T>
struct X {
   void foo() { std::cout << "generic\n"; }
};
// specialize just this member for `int`
template <>
void X<int>::foo() { std::cout << "int\n"; }
int main() {
   X<double> xd; xd.foo();  // generic
   X<int>    xi; xi.foo();  // int
}

// Class template specialization
template <typename T>
struct X {
   void foo();
}
template <typename T>
struct X<T*> {
   void bar();
}
template <typename T>
void X<T>::foo() { std::cout << "generic\n"; }
template <typename T>
void X<T*>::bar() { std::cout << "ptr\n"; }
int main() {
   X<int > xi; xi.foo();       // generic
   X<int*> xp; xp.bar();       // ptr
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do, and it is not redundant because `Queue` is not a type without a template parameter. However, you can provide the function definition inside of the class template declaration:

```
template <class ItemType>
class Queue
{
    Queue();
    ItemType dequeue() { /* implementation */}
    int count() { /* implementation */ }
    /* ... other methods ... */
};
```

Bear in mind that this

```
Queue<int> q;
int i = q.dequeue();
```

is equivalent to

```
Queue<int> q;
int i = Queue<int>::dequeue(&q);
```

in other words, the full type is needed to qualify the function name, even if the function itself does not reference the template parameter (although in this case, the template parameter is needed for the return type).

Comment: If it were not for specializations this would not be needed (the example is Java): the syntax in the language could use the name of the template to refer to the type obtained after instantiation, in the same way it does within the definition of a class template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> When a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, a static data member or a member
> template of a class template is defined outside of the class template definition, the member definition is
> defined as a template definition in which the template-parameters are those of the class template. The
> names of the template parameters used in the definition of the member may be different from the template
> parameter names used in the class template definition.